# Daily spending limit option not visible in App Engine's Settings

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I cannot see the daily spending limit option in Google App Engine's Settings page:

[image]

Why?

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm using the Standard Environment.

Answer (score 1):

I got below reply from google team on above mention issue >>>

The Cloud App Engine product team confirmed that the reason because of the spending limit is not available is that we are currently in the process of making changes to the way people can manage their costs in App Engine.

This means that all projects that did not have a spending limit set on them are unable to set them now.
Spending limits that have already been set should continue to be respected for now.

The current spending limit feature is in the process of being replaced with a more flexible option that will allow for more control in the exact costs being measured.
We are working on the documentation, which will include step-by-step instructions on how to set-up the new measures. An official notice of the change will be going out as soon as possible and will include links to these docs.

In the meanwhile, you can take a look at this article [1](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify#cap_disable_billing_to_stop_usage) to implement a more flexible spending limit option. You can modify the cod there to disable the Google App Engine Application.

I hope this information was useful to you. Please, let me know if you have any questions. I will be more than happy to help you.

---

BTW thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you are using App Engine on the flexible environment as [according to documentation this is not supported](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#spending_limit). For application in App Engine Flex, you can use budgets and alerts as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/managing-projects-apps-billing#creating_budgets_and_setting_alerts).

Hope you find this information useful!

Comment: rsalinas thanks for your reply, As I am I'm using the Standard Environment on my app engine

Comment: If you are using the Standard environment and still are unable to set spending limits, you may want to open a ticket to [GCP Support directly](https://cloud.google.com/support/) as they are able to inspect your project and would be able to properly identify if there is something wrong with your app engine or billing account which may be the root cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with that at the moment. It has been reported in [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/148125787) public Issue Tracker thread as well. Engineering is aware and are looking into it. You may show that you're also affected by clicking on the 'Star' button next to the Issue ID and to receive future updates regarding it.