# How to set a spending limit for firestore and react native app

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I use the firestore blazeplan for a react native application.
I would like to set the spending limit for firestore. I have the owner role and I followed the firestore documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#manage_spending

What is not mentioned in the firestore documentation is that setting spending limits is only available in a standard app engine environment.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/console/#setting_a_spending_limit

When I go to the app engine environment I have to choose a language. Depending on the language the standard environment is available. So my questions are:

- Does it matter which language I choose here to enable the standard environment for my app engine? Despite the fact that I don't use that language for my react native app.
- Will setting a random language and standard environment enable the option to set a limit to firestore spending for my react native App? Will the monitoring of firestore spending happen correctly? The other option is to select 'Other' but then the standard environment and presumably setting a spending limit is not available.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59837310/daily-spending-limit-option-not-visible-in-app-engines-settings

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter which language you choose as pretty much all of the options on there are supported on Standard as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/). The place where you define if you are using App Engine Standard or Flex is on the [app.yaml file.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref)

This will most likely enable the option to set the spending limit, I say "most likely" because there was a [recent issue](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/148125787) in which some users were not able to see the option. If this happens to you, I would suggest contacting [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) directly for them to check you console.

As for if the spending will be tracked correctly, most of the times the real time tracking it is done by an estimation. This means that no matter what, you are going to have a bit of a difference between the reported expenses and the billing at the end of the month. This more often than not end up being in benefit of the user.

Either way, I would suggest you to consider putting some [budget alerts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#budget) on your application in you are worried about your spending and this is available regardless of App Engine.

Hope you find this useful!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. After reading your answer I could select for instance node.js which enables the standard container and gives me the option to set the spending limits. I have my doubts though, because I don't use node.js with my react native app, so my expectation is that setting the spending limit on an empty node.js container/app engine won/t work as expected. Unfortunately the Firestore documentation isn/t very clear about how this works.

Comment: App Engine is used by other tools besides itself such as Firestore and Datastore for an example in order to track their billing, so you will not have any issue having an empty application and your Firebase functions.

Comment: Ok, I am ging to to add the App Engine and monitor it for a while and see what happens.

Comment: this explains a lot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59837310/daily-spending-limit-option-not-visible-in-app-engines-settings I also got this one confirmed from Google support.

Comment: Yes, that's an issue that is ongoing still https://issuetracker.google.com/148125787. I suggest you to add a comment and +1 in that issue so that they can give this more priority.